# Maven: Generate pom and run it in one command

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I need to perform the following process using Maven:

1. Download pom using valid GAV Modify part of the pom  *(doable) - Maven dependency:dependency-copy plugin*
2. Modify few lines in the pom *(doable) Maven replacer or ant-run plugins*
3. Execute mvn command on the new pom (**doable??**)

Is there a way to do it in one mvn run?

Comment: yes, the maven-release-plugin does a very similar thing. You may find some ideas there. who is executing these 3 steps? another maven plugin or a script?

Comment: Step 1 can be done with maven dependency plugin (dependency-copy),Step 2 can be done with maven ant run plugin or replacer plugin, I don't know how to perform the third